# gvfs and permissions on a remote external usb drive

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, gvfs, shared-folders, shared-disk

I have transmission and deluge (trying to see if it's a problem with the app) and I'm having the same problem with both of them.  When torrenting.  I get an error `" Operation not supported (/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=192.168.1.7,user=pi/media/ "`  when downloading a file.

1) My desktop machine has the torrent program on it (deluge / transmission) and it's connected to my raspberry pi (via ssh) which has an external usb drive connected to it.

2) I'm trying to run transmission on my desktop but have all the files go to the external usb drive located / connected to my raspberry pi.  This worked on 14.04LTS but I can't seem to get it to work on 16.04 LTS.   I created the group **torgrp** and placed the users in it but still I get the `" Operation not supported (/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=192.168.1.7,user=pi/media/ "`

```
when I do a 
ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 14 pi   torgrp 4096 Apr 22 10:46 media
```

but when I download and check the rights of the file (see below)

```
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi     1485881344 Apr 22 10:46 ubuntu-16.04-desktop
```

and the download stops after about 6meg and comes back with an error.  **Please note the file size below says it's correct but it's just holding that amount of space for the full download**

I also check to see if the users were in the group

```
id pi
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),105(netdev),999(input),1002(spi),1003(gpio),1004(torgrp)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you copy a file to the destination as the same user? It sounds like a special file operation are not supported over gvfs/sftp. Debugging with `strace` could give a hint. If the program can write some bytes, it is probably not a permission error. Can you run the programs directly on your raspberry pi?

Comment: @jofel  I can create and delete directories and files using nautilus but when I create a file I'm not allowed to edit the file I just created.  Not sure how to use strace.   Yes I have tested that I can run the programs directly on the pi.  It's some strange issue with permissions / external usb drives and gvfs but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.